# How to rename group files

Tags: rename

How to rename a group of files

```
tl_0014_0010_20151212_133443.jpg
tl_0014_0010_20151212_133543.jpg
tl_0014_0010_20151212_133643.jpg
...
```

to

```
photo00000.jpg
photo00001.jpg
photo00002.jpg
...
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started:

```
i=0
for file in tl*.jpg
do
    printf -v counter "%05d" $i
    mv $file photo$counter.jpg
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

The printf command ensures the counter has leading zeroes.

Note that I didn't test this.

Comment: The `-v` option to `printf` is a shell extension that's not supported in most Bourne shells.  A more portable method is `counter=$(printf "%05d" "$i")`.